# How to restore the deleted projects from teamcity

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, teamcity, devops, teamcity-9.0, devops-services

Accidently, I deleted the projects of some POC, Is there is any way to restore it ?? I was trying to get it back looking into the _trash in TeamCity data/config folder. The project is not there. Any other ways to retrieve it immediately???

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you will get deleted TeamCity project from `C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\config\_trash\DeleteProject.project~` directory

You can undo the deletion by moving the "config/_trash/DeleteProject.project~" to the "config/projects/DeleteProject" manually.